# How do I group items with same color

Tags: commerce

We use Drupal Commerce. Products in our catalogue have various colors and we have a filter for that. I don't want to see one product in ALL colors on the product list page, but only in one; say black.

When I apply the filter to 'white', I want to see all the products in white. Ideally, without the page reload.

Our catalogue is made with the Views module.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Search API?

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter of your color field and expose the filter.

Enable ajax for your view, it's listed under Advanced.

There is a catch though: I believe this only works for **page views** only and not for block views.